# Expose "use" classes to Included file

Tags: php, namespaces, include

Example:

```
namespace Somenamespace;    
use Somenamespace\Someclass;
use Somenamespace\otherclass;


class Template{

  public function display($templ){
    load_template($templ);
  }

}


function load_template($file){
  unset($file);
  require func_get_arg(0);
}

$template = new Template();
$template->display('file.php');
```

Now I want to access "Someclass" in file.php, without having to declare it first in the "use" statement. eg. `someclass::dostuff();` (without the namespace)

Is it possible?

Comment: You mean like `$Someclass = \Somenamespace\Someclass();` and `$otherclass = \Somenamespace\otherclass()`.

Comment: but without having to specify the namespace

Comment: yes but I don't want to put that in file.php. Can it be done without?

Comment: You may want to consider [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) your classes to avoid the need for `use` altogether.

Comment: @MichaelMior autoloading can not replace `use`

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Why not (in this case)? If you autoload classes in `Somenamespace`, `someclass` would be available without needing `use`.

Comment: @MichaelMior no, if you write `new someclass` in `file.php` (without any namespace declaration or `use`), this will trigger autoload that will include file with `\Somenamespace\someclass` and will result with fatal error, since `someclass` is still missing.

Comment: A quite similar problem is, that it also does not work vice versa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044229/php-use-in-include-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply: no. See note bellow the example http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-247

> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will ***NOT*** inherit the parent file's importing rules.