# PHP: "use" in include files?

Tags: php, namespaces

When using namespaces in PHP you can do things like:

```
<?php
use \mynamspace\MyClass;
$a = new MyClass();
?>
```

Is it possible to put the use... line in an include file? If there are dozens oft those use statements it is very annoying to write them in every single file you need them.

But the use statement is only working for the current file and is ignored in the files that include it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using the use statement like this `use mynamespace\Myclass as Myclass;` maybe the namespace will be recognised by included files. Although if you break out of a class i don't think the use statement will be recognised.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not. PHP's namespace constructs are in a per file basis. The PHP manual sums it up as such:

> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT
>   inherit the parent file's importing rules.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: OK. Since included files will not inherit the parents rules, I guess the same applies to my problem. So the parent files will not get the rules of the included file.

Thanks anyway...